# Is this system time variant?

Tags: lti-system

I was reading out a book and it said to prove that 
\$y(t) = sin (t)  x(t-2)\$
is time variant, so far of all the inputs I have tried, as well as the general input of giving a shift of T, the system seems to be time invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system **is** time variant because plugging in \$x(t-a)\$ does **not** equal \$y(t-a)\$.

For the first case you get:
\$y_1(t)=sin(t)x(t-a-2)\$

However, if you offset the output by a you get:
 \$y_2(t)=y(t-a)=sin(t-a)x(t-a-2)\$

Since \$y_1(t)\$ does **not** equal \$y_2(t)\$ the system **is** time variant. Look at the first example on this page if you are confused: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system

Answer (score 0):

The system is time variant. Forget about the t-2 and think about what happens with sin(t) when you start the input at time t=0 as apposed to time t=pi/2 .

In both of these cases, let the input be a dirac delta function. In the first case, you should get nothing out, and in the second you would get the delta function back out.

Comment: I had thought the same but the example of an RC circuit came in my mind in which  a delayed sinusoidal input gives a delayed sinusoidal output

Comment: oh hang on, now I get it :) thankyou